# How do I decrease the timeout on ifup?

Tags: server, networking, scripts

I'm writing a shell script that brings up an Ethernet interface (configured for DHCP) to determine whether it's connected to a network. If it isn't, I'd like to be able to report in a timely manner (within a few seconds) that there's no connection. Unfortunately, in the absence of a connection, ifup seems to wait several minutes before timing out, and the man page doesn't mention a timeout parameter. Is there any way to stop it after a few seconds?

This is on Ubuntu Server 11.10; NetworkManager is not in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way.

As it turns out, since what I really want to do is check for link, I don't need `ifup` at all. Instead, I can use `ethtool` (though it has to be installed first), like so:

```
connected=$(ethtool eth0 | awk '/Link detected:/ { print $3 }')
```

If, however, I did need to check `ifup`, I could use a background process and the `$!` shell variable. If I just wanted to check whether it was still running after the timeout, I could do this:

```
ifup eth0 &
sleep 5
if ps -p $! | grep -q "$!"; then
    connected='no'
    kill $!
else
    connected='yes'
fi
```

If I wanted to capture the output from `ifup`, my best bet would probably be to redirect it to a temporary file. (I looked into named pipes, but I don't think they'd work for this purpose; `ifup` would block until another process was reading its output.)

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what you are using for a notification.

```
[[ -n "$(ifconfig | grep '192.*' )" ]] || echo "down"
```

Change "192" to the prefix of your network (192.168.x.y is most common).

Change "echo "down"" to your notification.

Run that command from cron with some reasonable interval.

Perhaps something along the lines of

```
[[ -n "$(ifconfig | grep '192.*' )" ]] || dhclient eth0
```

run once a minute or so ?

Comment: This isn't a periodic notification thing. It's part of a network setup process, and I'm just trying to figure out "is eth0 physically connected to a network or not?"